# Creating a Treeview Listing of a Directory

Tags: customization, navigation, directory

Within the WordPress core, I created a folder called /reports and within that directory are about 15 other folders containing .pdf's.

As an example : Core File Structure

/wp-admin 
/wp-content 
/wp-includes 
**/reports**

As an example : Reports File Structure

**/reports**
      - /folder-1
             - abcdefg.pdf
             - abcdefg.pdf
      - /folder-2
             - abcdefg.pdf
             - abcdefg.pdf
      - /folder-3
             - abcdefg.pdf
             - abcdefg.pdf

What I am trying to accomplish is to: grab that folder structure within /reports and display that same file structure on a custom template, like in a Treeview format. This is being built for the purpose of a sales team being able to quickly access this directory of reports and download the pdf file. Not 100% sure if this can be done.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How is your case specific to WP? Seems to be a more generic PHP programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with WordPress, but anyway, in your template you can grab the directory structure with [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php):

```
$report_files = scandir('/reports');
```

Now you have array of files and folders that you can manipulate ate will.